# Stacked barchart with three categorical and one numrical columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have dataset which has three categorical variables

```
data_input <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L),
 .Label = c("CHEER","CHOIR", "DEEP", "OVER", "PEER", "PEEN", "POST"), 
class = "factor"), 
Var2 = c("Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", 
"Bad", "Bad", "Good", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", 
"Bad", "Bad", "Bad", "Bad"), 
Type = c("New", 
"New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", 
"Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", 
"Old"), value = c(0, 0, 4, 28, 4, 7, 8, 10, 3, 2, 36, 10, 
23, 31, 7, 19, 3, 14, 12, 4)), 
.Names = c("Var1", "Var2", "Type", "value"), 
row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I used following code to generate the plot

```
ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = reorder(Var1, Var2), y = value)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", aes(fill = Var2)) +
labs(y = "\n Total Number of Counts", x = NULL)
```

It generates a plot like [image]

However, it does not distinguish between different types visually. Can we have different colors for different types or something to distinguish them from one another along with the legend.

Comment: What do you mean, `does not distinguish between different types visually`? It shows the two levels in `Var2`? Which variables do you want shown differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be two solutions. First, change color around bars according to `Type`.

```
ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = reorder(Var1, Var2), y = value)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", aes(fill = Var2,color=Type),size=1) +
      scale_color_manual(values=c("black","grey75"))+
      labs(y = "\n Total Number of Counts", x = NULL)
```

[image]

Second, use interaction between `Type` and `Var`2 for filling.

```
ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = reorder(Var1, Var2), y = value)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", aes(fill = interaction(Type,Var2))) +
      labs(y = "\n Total Number of Counts", x = NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

While your question is not entirely clear to me, you are not using the variable `type` in your plot at all, so that is one thing to change.

Now, when you have thee dimensions, you may want to facet it; separating out the data into separate panels, here using the type variable (`New` subset on the left; `Old` on the right):

```
ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = Var1, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", aes(fill = Var2)) +
  facet_wrap(~Type)+
  labs(y = "\n Total Number of Counts", x = NULL)
```

[image]